# Use regular expression within constructor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, constructor

I've been having trouble trying to define a third property of a constructor. When I comment out `this.partial = text.replace(cloze,'...');` it runs fine. 
But when I use that line of code, the program ends mid-inquirer. I believe it has something to do with the `.replace()` regex.
Here's my code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var action = process.argv[3];
var count = process.argv[4];

function ClozeCard(text, cloze) {
    this.text = text;
    this.cloze = cloze;
    this.partial = text.replace(cloze,'...');
}

var inquirer = require('inquirer');

var cards = [];

var num = 0;

var start = {
    createCards: function() {
      if (num < count) {
        inquirer.prompt([
          {
            name: "text",
            message: "What is the Cloze-flashcard's text?"
          }, {
            name: "cloze",
            message: "What is the Cloze-flashcard's answer?"
          }
        ]).then(function (answers) {

          var newCard = new ClozeCard(answers.text, answers.cloze);
          if (answers.text.indexOf(answers.cloze) === -1) {
            console.log("The answer does not appear to be in the text. Try again");
            return;
          } else {
              cards.push(newCard);
              num++;
              fs.writeFile('cloze.txt', JSON.stringify(cards), function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
              });
              start.createCards();
          }
        });
      }
    }
}

start.createCards();

module.exports = ClozeCard;
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Where is the regular expression? Isn't `cloze` a string?

Comment: There's no error message the program just ends before Im allowed to enter a prompt. Sorry by regular expression I meant the replace() function, that is where I think its giving me problems

Comment: You don't call the `CloseCard` constructor until *after* the prompt. So I don't see how anything in there could be the cause of the problem. Unless there's a syntax error that prevents the rest of the code from being executed at all. What happens if you move the function definition after `var start = ...;`?